# trying to get partial match from laravel $errors->has()

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I'm starting to wonder if this is possible at all, but I'm using Laravel and I need to check to see if the $errors object contains any keys containing a search string.
I know it contains the keys 'monitors.0.size' and 'monitors.1.size' but I need to be able to check using just 'monitors'.
$errors->has('monitors') returns false and the attempts I've made at inserting different wildcards have resulted in page errors.
Am I missing something simple?  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as `$errors` is an instance of `\Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` I think the only way would be to loop over the $errors and compare them.

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't thinking about the object properly and you put me back on track.